# The support of function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is $\operatorname {supp} (f)=\{x\in (0, +∞)\}$, is it?

Tags: measure-theory

In mathematics, the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#In_probability_and_measure_theory) of a real-valued function f is the subset of the domain containing those elements which are not mapped to zero.

Suppose that f : X → R is a real-valued function whose domain is an arbitrary set X. The set-theoretic support of f, written supp(f), is the set of points in X where f is non-zero

$\operatorname {supp} (f)=\{x\in X\,|\,f(x)\neq 0\}$

let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$

$\operatorname {supp} (f)=\{x\in (0, +∞)\}$

So, the support of function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is $\operatorname {supp} (f)=\{x\in (0, +∞)\}$, is it?

Comment: By the way, $\{x \in (0, +\infty)\} = (0, +\infty)$.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite. The support of a function $f$ is usually the *closure* of the set $\{x\mid f(x)\neq 0\}$ (it even says so in the wikipedia article you linked). So in most circumstances, for the square root function, the support would contain $0$ (assuming you include $0$ in the domain). Of course, if closure doesn't make sense (there is no topology on the domain considered), then the closure operation isn't carried out.